# I need to add signature on SharePoint 2016 list form

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online

I explored certain ways of acheiving the above requirement as per links below , but doesnt work out.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/digital-signatures-in-infopath-2010-8a03da0b-31c7-4c47-b78d-56c237c9c373?ocmsassetID=HA010381868&CorrelationId=3e730dfc-03f5-4361-bd6a-34e310d5c55b&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US - Compatibility issue with browser

http://www.aerieconsulting.com/blog/signature-field-for-sharepoint-lists

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/849558/Capture-signature-or-hand-written-notes-in-SharePo - SharePoint forms designer tool throws error while installed from link mentioned.

http://sympmarc.com/2014/07/22/using-the-signature-pad-jquery-plugin-with-sharepoint-infopath/

Could you please let me know if there is any 3rd party tool/ other simplest way to achieve this in SharePoint 2016 ? Thanks

Comment: What error it throws?

Comment: @SigarDave :  The error was thrown because i was installing the exe on a standalone machine. It should be installed in SharePoint server it seems.

Comment: @SigarDave : Is there any other way to achieve it in a simpler way ?

Comment: I am not sure, but found out this github link which provides a way for digital signature https://github.com/zmullett/sharepoint-digital-signature-field and this one
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e149674f-4a7c-4215-87aa-ed49b665cbad/requirements-for-enabling-signature-signing-in-sharepoint-2013-web-based-form?forum=sharepointcustomization

Comment: I am not sure. :(